# Configure LinkedServer to FileStream in DataBase

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filestream, linked-server

Assume this Table in SQL Server 2008 that used FILESTREAM type:

```
CREATE TABLE MyFsTable
(
  fId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  fData VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM  NULL,
  fName NVARCHAR(300),
  RowGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  NOT NULL  ROWGUIDCOL UNIQUE DEFAULT NEWID()
);
```

Then I insert an Access file (.accdb) to this table.

So, I need a linked server to this file in database but I don't know how configure the datasource of linked server, the all samples I seen are like the following:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'ACCESS', @srvproduct=N'access',
@provider=N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', @datasrc=N'f:\test.accdb' 
GO
```

But I don't want to use Disk location, How can I configure datasource of this LinkedServer to the File as FileSTREAM in Database? Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a linked server to use FileStream.
If a column is given the data type FILESTREAM then when you select that column SQL Server will read the placeholder in the column and direct the query to the disk location automatically.

Are you inserting the Access Database frequently or once? You can use a Linked Server to import data from an MS Access database ..... but that MS Access database must be on a disk soemwhere on the network.